# Does the "woocommerce_thankyou" action hook fire on failed orders?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

My affiliate script tracks a conversion after an order is placed. it runs inside the `woocommerce_thankyou` action hook:

```
function affiliate_tracking_code( $order_id ) {

    // get the order info for the script

    ?>

    <script>

       // affiliate script here

    </script>

    <?php

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'affiliate_tracking_code', 10, 1 );
```

I do not want this script to fire if the order has failed or is pending. Only if it is successful. I can not find in the documentation whether or not the `woocommerce_thankyou` action hook fires for anything but successful orders.

If it does then what is the best way to make sure that my script only tracks conversions for successful orders and not failed ones.?

One way I have tested is to wrap my script in an if and check `if ( $order->get_status() == 'processing' ) : // run the script` however I am not sure if there are hidden loopholes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will fire or failed orders as well.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_thankyou', 'woocommerce_before_thankyou_failed_order')

function woocommerce_before_thankyou_failed_order( $order_id ) {
    
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    if ( !$order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) { 
        // if order not failed
    }
}
```

See the hook under `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/thankyou.php`